# Will the wobbly windows effect be in Ubuntu 11.04?

Tags: 11.04, compiz

Will the wobbly windows effect be available in Ubuntu 11.04?

Answer (score 5):

You will certainly be able to enable the effect via `ccsm` from the package `compizconfig-settings-manager` , but it won't be on by default.

Comment: Do you know this for sure, or speculating? Also note to those who do turn it on via CCSM, it will crash unity, restart the computer and unity will be back up with wobbly windows.

Comment: It's pure speculation based on the absence of reasons to disallow simple effect plugins in combination with Unity. Btw., you don't need to restart your computer, just Compiz.

Comment: You won't need to restart compiz. Compiz plugins are auto-loaded.

Comment: Not if Compiz crashes. ;-)